# problems with BlockUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a problem using blockUI in jQuery. See the use case below:

```
<form action:"javascript:processInfo()" id="myForm">
     ...
     ...
<input type = "submit" value ="submit" id ="submit"/>
</form>
```

The processInfo() javascript function is like this:

```
function processInfo(){
   $.blockUI({message:"<h1>Please Wait....</h1>"});
   .....//some processing here
   $.unblockUI();
}
```

The problem is that this blockUI is function is never called. However, the effect of this is seen after the entire javascript function processInfo() is completed. What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix this. Please help.

Comment: one thing to mention, if you are using blockUI.js, please be friendly for us Firefox Linux users and add $.blockUI.defaults.applyPlatformOpacityRules = false; so that it works on our browsers!

Comment: Ah, I never knew about that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I generally would approach it by the using the following:

```
<form action="/url_to_submit_to" id="myForm">
     ...
     ...
<input type = "submit" value ="submit" id ="submit"/>
</form>
```

Then in you script have

```
$(function() {
   $("#myForm").submit(function() {
      $.blockUI({message:"<h1>Please Wait....</h1>"});
      .....//some processing here
      $.unblockUI();      
   });
});
```